Routing of Database usinng MultiTenancy in Spring
I am trying to implement multi-tenancy in spring. I ma using JWT, and I have the tenant_id stored in the JWT, I have configured my class MultiTenantDataSourceRouter extending  AbstractRoutingDataSource to have the lookup key to be the tenant_id.
@Override
protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
    var authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if(authentication!= null && authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof User user) {
        return user.getTenant_id();
    }
    return null;
}

I also have a controller method that logins in a user. Upon login, I want to create an object of the user and store it in the database that is suppose to be particular to that Tenant
public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> loginUser(AuthenticateRequest authenticateRequest) {
            //authenticate the User
            authenticationManager
                    .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticateRequest.getEmail(),authenticateRequest.getPassword()));

            //this line of code runs oly if authentication is successful
            User user = userRepository.findByEmail(authenticateRequest.getEmail()).orElseThrow();
            String jwt = jwtService.generateToken(user);

            //set the security context to allow routing of db and to know the tenantID and also set the datasource
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(),null,user.getAuthorities()));

            var mds = new MultiTenantDataSourceRouter();
            mds.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceConfig.loadAllDataSources());
            mds.afterPropertiesSet();

            //create an Employee Object for the user once
            Employee employee = employeeRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
            if(employee!= null){
                Employee newEmployee = Employee.builder()
                        .email(user.getEmail())
                        .name(user.getName())
                        .build();
            }
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt));
    }

Upon start of the app I have the datasources loaded (dataSourceConfig.loadAllDataSources()) this is a bean that returns the Map of tenant_id and the corresponding datasources.But when I call this method the default datasource loaded in the app through app.properties is where the employee object is where the findbyEmail() method is being looked for. I am expecting that it looks for it inside the tenant associated with that user but it doesnt
This results in an error because my default database does not have employee table.
I have edited the TenantRouterClass. I now have the class below. The idea is that when the ap starts up, it will check the default tenant store, which contains information used to create the other datasources available.
package dev.iyanu.multitenancy.security_config;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import dev.iyanu.multitenancy.entities.Tenants;
import dev.iyanu.multitenancy.repository.TenantRepository;
import dev.iyanu.multitenancy.users.User;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class TenantManager {

    private final TenantRepository tenantRepository;
    private final Map<Object,Object> tenantDataSources = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Getter
    private Object currentTenant;
    private AbstractRoutingDataSource dataRouter;

    public TenantManager(TenantRepository tenantRepository, DataSource dataSource) {
        this.tenantRepository = tenantRepository;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    //before you do a save or interact with the db call this method
    public void setCurrentTenant() {
        var auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(auth != null && auth.getPrincipal() instanceof User user){
            this.currentTenant = user.getTenantId();
        }
    }


    @PostConstruct
    public DataSource loadAllDataSources(){
        dataRouter = new AbstractRoutingDataSource() {
            @Override
            protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
                return currentTenant;
            }
        };
        List<Tenants> tenantsList = tenantRepository.findAll();

        if(!tenantsList.isEmpty()){
            for(Tenants tenant : tenantsList){
                DataSource tenantDatasource = createDataSource(tenant);
                tenantDataSources.put(tenant.getTenantId(),tenantDatasource);
            }
        }
        tenantDataSources.forEach((tenantId, ds)->{
            var schemaInitializer = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(new ClassPathResource("schema.sql"));
            schemaInitializer.execute((DataSource) ds);
        });
        dataRouter.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSource);
        System.out.println("Default DataSource: "+dataSource);
        dataRouter.setTargetDataSources(tenantDataSources);
        System.out.println("DataSources loaded from my repo: "+tenantDataSources);
        dataRouter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return dataRouter;
    }


    public void addTenant(Tenants tenants){
        //create the Db for the Client
        createDatabase(tenants);

        //create datasource for the client
        DataSource newDataSource = createDataSource(tenants);

        //just to check that the new tenant added already has his datasource active
        try(Connection c = newDataSource.getConnection()){
            tenantDataSources.put(tenants.getTenantId(),newDataSource);
            dataRouter.afterPropertiesSet();
            System.out.println("The new tenant datasource is live");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    private DataSource createDataSource(Tenants tenants){
        var properties = new DataSourceProperties();
        properties.setPassword("root");
        properties.setUsername("root");
        properties.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        properties.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"+tenants.getDatabaseName());
        return properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }

    private void createDatabase(Tenants tenants){
        try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()){
            var databaseName = StringUtils.substringBefore(tenants.getName()," ");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE "+databaseName);
            log.info("Database for {} created successfully", tenants.getName());
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }





}

So when a user tries to login, I authenticate the user, set the securitycontextholder and the call the setCurrentTenant() method before making a call to the Emloyee.findByEmail(email) method. I expect the method to call the datasource associated with the call but it didnt, it still routed to the defaultDatabase that has been set

public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> loginUser(AuthenticateRequest authenticateRequest) {
            //authenticate the User
            authenticationManager
                    .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticateRequest.getEmail(),authenticateRequest.getPassword()));

            //this line of code runs oly if authentication is successful
            User user = userRepository.findByEmail(authenticateRequest.getEmail()).orElseThrow();
            String jwt = jwtService.generateToken(user);

            //set the security context to allow routing of db and to know the tenantID and also set the datasource
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user,null,user.getAuthorities()));

            tenantManager.setCurrentTenant();
        Object currentTenant = tenantManager.getCurrentTenant();
        System.out.println(currentTenant);

        //create an Employee Object for the user once
            Employee employee = employeeRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
            if(employee!= null){
                Employee newEmployee = Employee.builder()
                        .email(user.getEmail())
                        .name(user.getName())
                        .build();
            }
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt));

    }

The currentTenant being printed is the the one associated with the datasource that I am expecting but it is still not routing to the right database and routes to the default targetDataSource.

Have a look at this example.
I believe you're missing a step here where you tell your application which tenant it needs to use for your employee. You're giving your multi-tenant datasource some datasources with your dataSourceConfig.loadAllDataSources(), but you're not telling it which one to use, so it uses the default one.

I thought the determine lookup key is suppose to come up and check the lookup key which is the tenant ID then route to the datasource that maps to that lookup key?

@OmotosoIyanu Indeed, that should work. Could you share your MultiTenantDataSourceRouter class and application.properties configuration? I'm curious about why you create a new instance of MultiTenantDataSourceRouter and set the datasources in your controller.

@OmotosoIyanu this link might also help. Note that in both links I shared, they have some setCurrentTenant() method or something similar that they use during runtime. That's what I think you're missing, assuming your configuration in MultiTenantDataSourceRouter is correct

thank you for the links. I am studying them but I do not want to use the ThreadLocal directly in my stage, I want to use the SecurityContextHolder so spring can manage the thread and I can just use that information to get my result. I will update on if I am able to get it to work

I have edited the code but still the same result, I have explained better in the post

Thanks for the added details.
Why do you use @PostConstruct? can you try replacing this with @Bean and @Primary annotations? This will set your multi-tenant datasource as the default bean to use.
I assume you're using a JPA repository, right? you might also need to add @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.your.repository") annotation to your configuration class

I am using @PostConstruct because I have a datasource configured in my app.properties which will load as the default database. If i change it to @Bean it will result in cyclic dependency because to load this bean I will then need to make a call to the tenantRepository which is  also dependent on the bean DataSource.
So I used @PostConstruct so when the main datasource loads, then i can load the other dataSources. This is because the info of the datasource to load is inside the repository of the Tenant TenantRepository

Is there a reason you keep your default datasource as a separate bean?\ 
dataRouter.setDefaultTargetDataSource(dataSource) doesn't need a specific bean for your default Datasource. You could simply have a private method in your TenantManager class that creates your datasource. Then just call it when setting the default datasource dataRouter.setDefaultTargetDataSource(getMyDefaultDatasource())

Because I have other classes in my project that have Repositories injected in them and they are also beans either @Config or @Service,  I am having cyclic dependency issues. This is as a result of the default DataSource not loaded inside the bean yet

Do the other repositories use different datasources? Or do they use the default one and/or the multi tenant one?

So I have one repository that contains the information of the multi tenant datasources. So I have finally being able to solve the issue. The link you posted was of great help. I basically had to first configure two different datasources when the application starts up and provide transaction and entity beans configurations..Thank you very much
